# Pandas apply() function behave differently depending on what is returned?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I'm calling `apply()` on a pandas data frame, but it seems that the applied function is invoked twice when it's returning arrays and once when it's returning floats.

Consider the following example.

```
from pandas import DataFrame
from numpy.random import random

def array_or_float(flag, x):
    """ Either return a random array or float depending on `flag` """

    if flag:
        value = random((2,1))

    else:            
        value = random()

    print('Got', round(x, 5), 'returns', value)

    return value

df = DataFrame({'A values': random(3)})
df['B values'] = df.apply(lambda x: array_or_float(True, x['A values']), axis=1)

print('\nData frame:')
print(df)
```

If I call `array_or_float(False)` inside the `apply()`, i.e., if I want the function to only return floats, then the output is consistent.

```
Got 0.46005 returns 0.6578862349718622
Got 0.64534 returns 0.8690478424766472
Got 0.04175 returns 0.41617107157789923

Data frame:
   A values  B values
0  0.460050  0.657886
1  0.645342  0.869048
2  0.041752  0.416171
```

However, if I call `array_or_float(True)`, i.e. I want to get arrays, then there seems to be an "orphaned" call that doesn't even get applied to the data frame, namely the first one.

```
Got 0.88822 returns [[0.31850227]
 [0.66878704]]
Got 0.88822 returns [[0.70890116]
 [0.9087984 ]]
Got 0.51507 returns [[0.92748729]
 [0.98650649]]
Got 0.91706 returns [[0.82387122]
 [0.86967768]]

Data frame:
   A values                                      B values
0  0.888216  [[0.7089011570815329], [0.9087983994394716]]
1  0.515068    [[0.92748728847228], [0.9865064881611074]]
2  0.917061  [[0.8238712182074142], [0.8696776790080818]]]
```

My specs are as follows:

- Python 3.6.8
- NumPy 1.15.4
- pandas 0.24.0

What's going on?

Comment: This is by design, see [Notes in pandas api documentation for apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)  "apply calls func twice on first row / column to determine slow or fast code path"

Comment: Why does it happen with arrays and not with floats, though? I edited the question to focus on this difference.